# Error en comunicación cliente / servidor localhost en Java

Tags: java, socket, puertos, tcp

Estoy comenzando con el tema de sockets en Java, y no logro hacer funcionar el programa más sencillo: abrir un puerto dentro del mismo equipo para conectar cliente y servidor, y establecer la comunicación bidireccional. Entiendo que la dirección IP en este caso debería ser "localhost", y que cualquier puerto que no esté en uso sería viable.

Aquí están las clases:

**Servidor**:

```
package simple_tcp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {

    public Server() throws Exception {
        
        // Abriendo el puerto:
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2020); // línea 16
        System.out.println("Puerto 2020 abierto.");
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("El cliente " + socket.getInetAddress() + " está conectado.");
        
        // Inicializo buffers I/O:
        BufferedReader inSocket = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter outSocket = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()), true);
        
        // Envío mensaje al cliente:
        outSocket.println("Bienvenido!");
        
        // Recibo mensaje del cliente:
        String mensajeCliente = inSocket.readLine();
        System.out.println("Mensaje del cliente: " + mensajeCliente);
        
        // Cerrando el socket:
        socket.close();
        System.out.println("Se cerró el socket del lado del servidor.");
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new Server(); // línea 40
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
}
```

**Cliente**:

```
package simple_tcp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {
    
    public Client() throws Exception {
        
        // Conectando con el servidor:
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",2020);
        System.out.println("Conexión exitosa con el servidor.");
        
        // Inicializo buffers I/O:
        BufferedReader inSocket = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter outSocket = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()), true);
        
        // Recibo mensaje del servidor:
        String mensajeServidor = inSocket.readLine();
        System.out.println("Mensaje del servidor: " + mensajeServidor);
        
        // Envío mensaje al servidor:
        outSocket.println("Gracias!");
        
        // Cerrando el socket:
        socket.close();
        System.out.println("Se cerró el socket del lado del cliente.");
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new Client();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
}
```

Cuando ejecuto el programa del lado del servidor, abre el puerto y se queda esperando. Pero cuando lo ejecuto del lado del cliente, me aparece esta excepción:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:555)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:544)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.bind(NioSocketImpl.java:640)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:392)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:274)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:167)
    at simple_tcp.Server.<init>(Server.java:16)
    at simple_tcp.Server.main(Server.java:40)
```

He probado con diferentes números de puerto, e incluso he verificado que estuvieran libres (al menos no aparecen en el listado de TCPView), y siempre obtengo el mismo resultado.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Probaste a poner "127.0.0.1" en la IP?? Imagino que el mensaje de error debe ser más largo que el trozo que has puesto, que no ayuda absolutamente. En algún punto te está diciendo el error exacto que tienes... por favor, cuando pases un mensaje de error no elijas qué parte pasar si no sabes qué es, mejor pasarlo entero.

Comment: @Benito-B, acabo de intentar con "127.0.0.1" en la IP y me da exactamente el mismo error, el cual lo incluí completo. No hay más nada en el mensaje de error. Gracias.

Comment: @Benito-B, te pido disculpas. Tenías razón, ya que al copiar y pegar me quedó afuera la primera línea. Es solo una línea, pero evidentemente es la más importante. Ya lo edité. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Lo he solucionado.

Es la primera vez que trabajo con un proyecto que tiene dos clases distintas, cada una con su método `main`.

Cuando quería ejecutar "del lado del cliente" me posicionaba en esa clase y nuevamente clicaba el icono de ejecutar pensando que estaba ejecutando ese archivo, cuando en realidad lo que estaba ejecutando era el proyecto completo, y lógicamente, se ejecutaba nuevamente del lado del servidor.

Pido disculpas especialmente a @Benito-B que se tomó el trabajo de ayudarme, y además con información insuficiente (ver comentarios).

Gracias a http://www.discoduroderoer.es/, que en su tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3wJTI9LMOsk propone un ejercicio similar y al momento de ejecutar el programa advierte sobre este error.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).